# Unable to find element by expath within a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to print the amount of gear needed for this character using the following code.  But I'm getting an error: unable to locate element.  I was doing some testing the amount of the for loop works and the one inside the for loop doesn't work.  Denoted by the comments in the code.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('log-level=3')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',options=options)
    
driver.get('https://msf.gg/characters/Iceman')
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('button')[1]
element.click()

amount = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/section/div/section/section/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/p/strong').text
print(amount)   #-----This works---------
    
gears = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bit')
#print(gears)
for gear in gears:
    amount = gear.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="app"]/section/div/section/section/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/p/strong').text
    print(amount)  #-----This doesn't work---------
```

Error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="app"]/section/div/section/section/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/p/strong"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error raised because there is no such element in "gears"

The correct way to do this:

```
gears = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bit')
time.sleep(3)
for gear in gears:
    amount= gear.text
    print(amount)
```